# Searchview hide Toast message in android

Tags: android, searchview, android-toast

I'm using a filtering SearchView. Everything works fine but, when you leave the keyboard to type and press a button, a kind of toast is shown. Anyone know how to remove it?
this is a my code:

```
  searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.buscador_lineas_transporte);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
            lvLineasTransporte.clearTextFilter();
        }
        else{
            lvLineasTransporte.setFilterText(newText);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: See here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857313/filter-text-display-in-searchview-not-removing

Comment: i tryed it but i have nullpoinexception in notifyDataSetChanged(),when i removed input values @ jo jo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Text Display in SearchView not removing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857313/filter-text-display-in-searchview-not-removing)